# Eloquent parent trait - Call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

`Notifiable` is a parent `trait` for multiple notifiable Eloquent models.

My issue is when I try to call `sendGCMNotifications` within the `Notifiable` trait,  i get the following error:

`"BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::sendGCMNotifications()"`

Here is my code:

```
trait Notifiable {      

    public function notifyUsers($params) {
        $notifications = // some array
        $this->sendGCMNotifications($notifications[0], $receiverIds);
        Notification::insert($notifications);
    }

    public function notifications() {
        return $this->morphMany('Notification', 'notifiable');
    }

    public function notifyCompanyAdmins($params) {
        $receiverIds = Company::with('users')->find($companyId)->users->lists('id');
        $this->notifyUsers(array_merge($params, ['receiverIds' => $receiverIds]));
    }
    public function sendGCMNotification($notification, $receiverIds, $action = NORMAL_NOTIFICATION) {

        foreach ($receiverIds as $id) {
            $registration_ids[] = User::find($id)->gcm_registration_id;
        }

        $response = Curl::post('https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send', [
            'data' => [
                'action' => $action,
                'message' => $notification['message']
                ],
            'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
            ]);

    }
}
```

Location model which inherits the above trait:

```
class Location extends Eloquent {
    use Confirmable, Notifiable;

    const NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = 'a location requires confirmation, submitted by #userFullName';
    const NOTIFICATION_TITLE = 'Location needs confirmation.';

    private $createdByAdmin;

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        Location::saved(function($location) {

            if (!$location->createdByAdmin) {
                $location->notifyCompanyAdmins([
                    'companyId' => Auth::user()->company_id,
                    'title' => self::NOTIFICATION_TITLE,
                    'message' => str_replace('#userFullName', Auth::user()->full_name, self::NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE),
                    'senderId' => Auth::user()->id,
                    ]);
            } else {
                $location->setConfirmed(['confirmed' => true, 'adminId' => Auth::user()->id]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method in the trait is `sendGCMNotification` not `sendGCMNotifications`. You missed the `s` off the end :)

Or it's the other way around - the call to `sendGCMNotifications` has an `s` that maybe shouldn't be there.

Either way you call it as `sendGCMNotifications` but define it as `sendGCMNotification`.

Comment: My dear god!! I was digging in other things, this didn't come to my mind:)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help someone in the future: I had this same problem because I had forgotten to add:

```
use xxx;
```

in the parent class.